# watir-webdriver-0.6.4 text_field cannot set japanese characters

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using watir-webdriver-0.6.4 and chrome browser to test my webpages.

Below is my code slice

```
@admin_browser.text_field(:name, "member[name]").set "そん"
```

It works fine if I replace "そん" with English characters, but with this code it behaves like this:
[image]

As you can see it changes into "]".

I ever searched in Japanese Google and they said I should use `.value = "そん"` instead of `.set "そん"`. But sadly this still doesn't work.

P.S. The ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p429. `gem update watir-webdriver` said nothing to update, so I believe watir-webdriver is the latest. I just downloaded the latest webdriver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.4/). My os is windows7 32bits.

P.S. again:

I just tested it on firefox and it works perfectly. Besides, I remember this code ever worked fine on chrome about a week ago and until just now I didn't update my ruby, watir-webdriver or chromedriver. So maybe the cause is the update of my chrome browser? I'll download an earlier version of chrome and try again.

Answer (score 1):

***Problem solved, a matter of Chrome version. I installed Chrome 29.0.1547.62 and all works fine. I guess this is a bug of latest chrome or the interface has been changed and the chromedriver developer is not noticed***